# Access individual items in a list

Tags: python, list

These two lines works:

```
all_text=["Happy"]    
if set(all_text).intersection("I'm HAPPY and SAD"):
```

These do no seem to work:

```
all_text=["Happy","SAD"]    
if set(all_text[0]).intersection("I'm HAPPY and SAD"):

all_text=["Happy","SAD"]    
if set(all_text[1]).intersection("I'm HAPPY and SAD"):
```

It seems that I can't access individual items.

Comment: Close the quotes first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `set()` on an iterable collects the iterable's items individually into a new set object.  So, doing `set(all_text[0])` is making a set out of the characters in the string `"Happy"`:

```
>>> all_text=["Happy","SAD"]
>>> set(all_text[0])
{'p', 'a', 'H', 'y'}
>>>
```

To do what you want, you need to put the string in a list:

```
>>> set([all_text[0]])
{'Happy'}
>>>
```

This will keep it from being broken up into characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `"` here:

```
all_text=["Happy", "SAD]
```

Actually in both places where you have the statement above. Copy and paste? Probably.